# Deserializing a value with no property to fill/match in class using newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I'm using C# and NewtonSoft framework to deserialize json. 
The JSON is from http://hearthstonejson.com/.
It looks like this. https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEQ5Q.png

```
   {"Basic":[
    {"id":"GAME_004","name":"AFK","type":"Enchantment","text":"Your turns are shorter."},
    {"id":"EX1_066","name":"Acidic Swamp Ooze","type":"Minion","faction":"Alliance","rarity":"Common","cost":2,"attack":3,"health":2,"text":"<b>Battlecry:</b> Destroy your opponent's weapon.","flavor":"Oozes love Flamenco.  Don't ask.","artist":"Chris Rahn","collectible":true,"howToGetGold":"Unlocked at Rogue Level 57.","mechanics":["Battlecry"]},
```

I can easily deserialize one set at a time into my classes but not all of the sets at once. The problem for me that I don't understand is the deserializer will fill each property with a value correctly but what if a value exists without a property in front of it to fill.

```
"id":"GAME_004"
```

will easily fill into

```
public string id;
```

but
 `{"Basic":[{"id":"GAME_004",`

("basic") or any other card set name won't fill in to anything unless it had a property to match to. I'm assuming I shouldn't need to know what the card set names need to be ahead of time. I should be able to just fill each set into a collection without having to know the name or is that wrong? Can I not assign the start of each object automatically to a property in my class without having to specifically know the name.

```
Token: StartObject
Token: PropertyName, Value: Basic
Token: StartArray
Token: StartObject
Token: PropertyName, Value: id
Token: String, Value: GAME_004
```

or must I just do the following for each individual set? Or am I missing a step in structuring my classes.

```
  List<IList<Card>> setsList = new List<IList<Card>>();
  JObject o = JObject.Parse(readContents2);
  JArray a = (JArray)o["Basic"];
  setsList.Add(a.ToObject<IList<Card>>());
  a = (JArray)o["Debug"];
  setsList.Add(a.ToObject<IList<Card>>());
```

I feel like that's doing it wrong since I'll have to update it each time a set is added.
The below should be enough (or a slightly modified form of it) to process all the sets from the json if my classes are structured correctly shouldn't it?

```
using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText("AllSets.json"))
            {
                JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                List<Card> myCards = (List<Card>)serializer.Deserialize(file, typeof(List<Card>));                
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to deserialize to dictionary of string, list:

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(readContents2);
var cards = a.ToObject<IDictionary<string, IList<Card>>>();
```

Or just

```
var cards = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string, IList<Card>>>(readContents2);
```

You will have a dictionary which contains a set name as a key, and cards as a value.

Check the example here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/m3rJYD